# How do you get Express server to keep track of the changes in the Pug view templates?

Tags: express, pug, server-side-rendering

I am using Pug for SSR in my application, but even after I make some changes to the pug views, Express does  not seem to keep track of them. Can someone help me out, because worse still, the bug made its way to production and I some stuck with old changes. Even when I delete the endpoint in my code, it still shows up the same old code. I also tried deleting the project and start over again, but nothing changed. Even when i delete the view file, it is like the endpoint still exists

Comment: Is there some kind of caching enabled? Are you sure your changes are overwriting the files on the server?

Answer (score 0):

After two long months of my tolerance being put to the test, I was finally able to find the solution to this. At first I thought Pug was the issue, then I tried Mustache for my template engine(check it out BTW, it's also cool) but the problem didn't seem to go anywhere.

The real issue is this: For some reason I had this file in my public directory called **index.html** and maybe when you use this line `app.use(express.static("public"))` express looks for that file and it seems to override the rest of the `res.render()` functions for the home route. However much I kept deleting the routes, it seemed to persist and that file kept on being served.

But after removing the **index.html** file from the root of the public **directory**, everything now works normal.